# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON') discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, slash

did i make mistake? or bug?

this is my index.js:

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()
const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
```

this is my commands/echo.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('echo')
    .setDescription('Replies with your input!')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('input')
            .setDescription('The input to echo back')
            .setRequired(true));
```

Comment: No idea without seeing all your command files. What do you export from them? Is it an object? Does it have a `data` key?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see the issue below here :
https://giters.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/6987

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).